# How long does maple syrup last in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, storage, maple-syrup

I have bought a biological (as per the label) maple syrup that states:

> Limited shelf life in the refrigerator after opening.

The bottle itself is 250mls and says that the portion size is 10ml and the number of services is 25.
My question is: does that mean that it can be consumed within 25 days? I don't really understand what the limited shelf life means in this case.
What should I watch out for to throw it away?

Comment: Limited shelf life in this context pretty much means archeologists in the far future finding that bottle wouldn't put in the content on their pancakes.

Comment: @Johannes_B: What does this mean? That the warning label is wrong?